# color fading with jquery without the color plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I look around to learn how to fade a background color using jquery, but all of the answers lead to the `jquery color plugin`, which I don't wanna use. I want a pure jquery code to do it but can't seem to find it. And my work place are very reluctant on using plugings for their site, so I must use pure jquery.

I'm not an expert in jquery but this is what I came up with, which I think is not the solution:

```
$('#fade').css('background-color', '#2CAEA8').animate({'opacity': 0});
```

I just want the background to fade to white from any color. Please can someone show me the way? Thank you.

Comment: Your workplace is missing a point. https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-color/master/jquery.color.js is small and lightweight, don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not write the the code yourself?

You know that FFFFFF is white, which can be interpreted as RGB 255 255 255

For example, you have a rgb (converted from hex) value 100 100 100 and then you just run a loop and increment those values till they reach 255, and set the background color to the matching on every iteration.

Comment: Posted a sample for this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="fade">
            some text goes here
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#fade').css('backgroundColor', $('#fade').css('backgroundColor')).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    }, 5000);

});
```

css

```
#fade{
    background:#ff0;
}
```

Comment: That's not true exactly because if you use ajax base jquery scripts you might be able to that without any problem, Box9.

Comment: @Box9, @Jack Billy: I cannot use jquery-ui or any plugins to make this background color effect. My company want it pure jquery, so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found your questions answer! Here it is a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/AN2b4/) or you can view the code below --

HTML --

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fade">
            My Friend Shaoz!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS --

```
div#fade
{
 color: #333;
 background: #ddd;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 font-family: segoe ui;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

Jquery --

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fadeobjid = 'fade';
    var fadetinobg = '#fff';
    var fadeouttobg = '#ddd';
    var fadeintotextcolor = '#000';
    var fadeouttotextcolor = '#333';
    var fadeinanimatespeed = '300';
    var fadeoutanimatespeed = '250';

    $('#' + fadeobjid).mouseover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'backgroundColor' : fadetinobg,
            'color' : fadeintotextcolor
        }, fadeinanimatespeed, 'linear', function() { });
    });
    $('#' + fadeobjid).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            'backgroundColor' : fadeouttobg,
            'color' : fadeouttotextcolor
        }, fadeoutanimatespeed, 'linear', function() { });
    });
});
```

The thing is that you will need the `jQuery-UI` to do this. That's all you need!

Hope this would help you!

Comment: My company don't wanna use the jquery-ui as it is quite heavy for the site we're building. They want it to be raw jquery, i.e. no plugins and no jquery-ui... Is there a way?

Comment: Sorry Shaoz, there is no way of doing this rather than using Flash.

Answer (score 0):

A simple/raw script for a "yellow fadeout", **no plugins except jquery itself**. Just setting background with rgb(255,255,highlightcolor) in a timer:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        yellowFadeout();
    });

    function yellowFadeout() {
        if (typeof (yellowFadeout.timer) == "undefined")
            yellowFadeout.timer = setInterval(yellowFadeout, 50);
        if (typeof (yellowFadeout.highlightColor) == "undefined")
            yellowFadeout.highlightColor = 0;
        $(".highlight").css('background', 'rgb(255,255,' + yellowFadeout.highlightColor + ')');
        yellowFadeout.highlightColor += 10;
        if (yellowFadeout.highlightColor >= 255) {
            $(".highlight").css('background','');
            clearInterval(yellowFadeout.timer);
        }
    }
</script>
```